# Create XLS file on server and return back to client without saving file on server in java

Tags: java, excel, struts2, apache-poi, jxl

In my strut2 base web application . I want to create XLS file when user click on download button without saving that file on server return back to client machine.

I have tried with different libraries but not found suitable solution.

also the save the file comes to client browser instead of download window is it possible to open save/cancel dialog box in which user can select file location to save .

Thanks

Comment: definitely possible. Lets see the answers

Comment: save the file comes to client browser instead of download window is it possible to open save/cancel dialog box in which user can select file location to save .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache POI provides `Workbook.write(java.io.OutputStream)`.   You should able to access the output stream and then write to it.

There are many hits comes from google - here is some that [is very close](http://www.coderanch.com/t/359397/Servlets/java/Write-Excel-file-browser-client).

That is (from Jim Garrison), do not open FileOutputStream.  Servlet will provide you output stream. Write on to it.  To help users with automatic filename or MIME handlers etc, do so the content disposition like possible filename.

Comment: yes i tried with this like fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);workbook.write(fos); so filepath required ? any other way to use outputStream

Comment: The output stream should come from Servlet (or what ever struts provide)

Comment: +1 - to clarify @Jayan's comment, you don't open a new `FileOutputStream`, you write to the one provided to you by the servlet in the response object.

Comment: @SwapnilSonawane :  Great-  I suspect jxl cannot support newer version of excel (xlsx- needed, if you plan to support more than 65k rows)